# htaccess with ctrl+f5 currect but f5 not working

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a react in the main root and a WordPress blog in its subfolder

|_ react
|_mag

react .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

    RewriteBase /mag
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I enter the address http://example.com/mag, I see a 404 page in react, and I press ctrl+f5 , I see WordPress, and I press f5 again, I see the 404 page of react again.
Please guide me how to view wordpress with f5?
tnx

Comment: RewriteBase is only relevant for the creation of the substitution URL, it has no influence on what URLs get matched in the first place - so your whole last block there does the same thing as the previous one, only with a different prefix for the substitution URLs. It serves no actual purpose for what you want to achieve here.

Comment: What you need to do, is add an _exception_ to this, so that all paths beginning with `/mag/`, don't get passed to the react router in the first place, but will still be handled by the web server, and then subsequently, by Wordpress.

Comment: tnx  CBroe
Exactly
But I don't know what the difference is, when I hit ctrl+f5 on the address example.com/mag, it works correctly, but when I hit f5 on the same address, a 404 react page is displayed.
I tried the following code but it didn't work
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ `https://example.com/mag/$1` [R=301,L]

Comment: The difference is that F5 is a normal reload - React can _intercept_ that reload, and then apply its own client-side routing functionality (and that doesn't find any content for `/mag/`, so you get a 404, _from_ react.) Ctrl+F5 however _forces_ a new request to the server to be made - and the _server_ knows about the existence of that directory, and can then serve the content from it.

Comment: _"I tried the following code but ..."_ - yeah, that has nothing whatsoever to do with what I suggested. You need to add an exception, so that these requests are _not_ rewritten to react's index.html. After the existing `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]` line, put `RewriteRule ^map/ - [L]`